QGIS specify map units for a document that does not have a projection defined
I have a QGIS project that does not have a coordinate reference system defined. This is deliberate, as I am working in a simple cartesian x,y model. The units of layer files are meters, and I want to add a scalebar to the layouts.
I can not figure out how to set the linear units to meters without specifying a coordinate system.
Is there a way to keep the coordinate reference system set to "No CRS" but specify the units as meters?

The scalebar properties in the layout allow you to select the units label to match your known map units. This allows me to draw a scalebar in a project without a CRS and choose the units from a drop-down box.
